# Nifi: PostHTTP Cannot send data to localhost:3000 because the destination does not accept FlowFiles

Tags: http-post, apache-nifi

I am new to Nifi and I am trying to do a PostHttp to send XML/JSON data to an nodejs app (it's on Localhost:3000)

I am using this processors:

[image]

But I get the next error: PostHTTP  Cannot send data to localhost:3000 because the destination does not accept FlowFiles and this processor is configureto deliver flowfiles.

Do I need to use other type of processor?

The App side, works properly (I have tried doing Posts with Insomnia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the property "Send as FlowFile" to "false" in PostHTTP.